# Modifying raster values in a zone with a math expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, conditional

I'm currently doing an SIG project with the goal of calculating groundwater volumes in chalk and silex residuals aquifers.

I have point data of underground water, chalk roof, and floor elevations, as well as RS thickness. The problem is that the chalk floor data points are visibly taken from an interpolation while roof and water are taken from measurements. As a result there're some locations were the floor elevation exceeds roof and/or water ones.

I have made TINs from the data points and then created rasters from those. I would like to update the raster cells in the zone where floor elevation are not correct. Those zones are high slopes (either valley or tectonic features), so basically the problem is that floor elevations do not follow the slopes that roof and water do follow.

How could I update those floor cell values according a the profile/slope of water/roof values? I thought about applying a math expression but couldn't find any way to do so.

Comment: For the record you can go directly from points to raster - a TIN isn't necessary. To solve your problem you're probably going to need to create a modifying raster and then use the Raster Calculator. The Conditional tool (Con) *might* also work. It depends on how you plan to apply the expression and what it is. For instance, will the floor be a consistent, set difference below roof/water? Will you be modifying floor independent of the other two (ie, you know what you want to set it to and it doesn't specifically relate to roof/water)?

Comment: (for the TIN, i read that it was more precise than going straight from points to raster when you have high resolution points distribution in some zones which is the case). For the problem i only need to edit the floor value in two zones. In the first so that it follows an average slope (taken in the roof gradient direction) of the roof and in the second one so that it follows an average slope (non linear, in the direction of the water gradient) of the water. I would plot a profile graph, and try to find a regression function and then apply it to the floor raster.

Comment: You're right, the TIN method is/can be more accurate if your sample points aren't evenly dispersed and appear in clusters. I'll post an actual answer outlining one process that will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of one way to do what you want - there may be others that are more efficient.

First, you need to create a binary Zone raster. This will be 0 for everything not in a zone and 1 for everything that is.

Then you'll need a raster of your modified values. You can use the current floor raster as a starting point and run Raster Calculator on it to modify *all* the values with a given formula, or you can create a whole new raster. You could take the roof raster and subtract a value from it to replicate the slope of values in the zone down to floor level. It does not matter if you end up with bad values outside the zone as a result of how you create the raster, just that they're right inside.

Finally you'll use the [Conditional (Con) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) to combine the two floor rasters into a new one based on zone. Con will look at a condition raster (your zone raster) - wherever the condition is met (zone = 0) it will use the value from a 'true' raster (your original floor raster); if the condition is not met (zone = 1) it will use the value from a 'false' raster (your modified floor raster).

Comment: I came to a similar solution. However i need to make the floor (realistically) lower than the roof, but not too  low. Since the floor data has no slope in it , just translating it will pose problems. I would need to be able to use an expression function of distance along the slope I.E:make a f(x) (x is distance along the slope or a cell number) modification but not f(y) (y are the elevation). The best i could find was to multiply the y's (elevations) by a coefficient (thus increasing the slope) then translating them so as to stay within the original values. It works only on linear functions.